# How to Distinguish an Object from Static Field and an Object from Non-Static Field/Variable

Tags: java, reflection

```
class A {
  static A STATIC_A = new A();
  A() {}
}

boolean isComingFromStaticField(Object a) {
  // returns true if a comes from static field, for example A.STATIC_A
  // returns false if a comes from non-static field/variable, for example new A()
  // .. or vice versa ...
}
```

In Java reflection, what will be the way to know the difference between an object from static field and a "normal" field/variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An instance (of class A in your example) is just an instance, a static variable in some class B may be pointing to it, but another non-static variable in class C may also be pointing to it. So you cannot make this check as it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as a "static instance" and a "normal instance". There are only static *variables* (and methods etc). So for example:

```
public class Foo {
    static Object bar = new Object();
    Object baz = bar;
}
```

Here the values of `baz` and `bar` refer to the same object - despite the fact that one variable is static and one is an instance variable.

Now if you *just* want to check whether a particular reference is equal to `A.STATIC_INSTANCE`, that's a simple reference equality check:

```
boolean isStaticInstance(Object a) {
    return a == A.STATIC_INSTANCE;
}
```

... but be aware that *all* that's checking is reference equality. You should avoid using misleading terminology like "static instance" after clarifying in your own mind what you really mean.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Btw, I've changed the method argument not to use (A a). Instead it's (Object a)

Comment: @HendraJaya: Okay - the same method body still applies. I've edited appropriately.